# boost udp::socket closes, but not freeing socket UPDATE

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, boost-asio

**UPDATE:** If i change `async_receive_from` to `receive_from` then there will not be any problems with rebinding. Somehow `async...` causes that. Previously i had one thread for every socket(with `receive_from`), but i had to make it work in one thread as too many threads are spawned during programm runs.

Socket is closed (i have checked), but rebinding to it causes an error. Here is an example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Mmsystem.h"// for accurate timers
 #pragma comment (lib,"Winmm.lib")// for accurate timers
using namespace std;

typedef shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> SHP_Socket;
boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
vector<int> ports;
vector<SHP_Socket> vecSock;
vector<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint> vecEndpoint;
vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>> receive_threads;
bool process_all_finishing;
uint8_t Data[8000];

void receive_h(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t szPack, int i)
{
    if (process_all_finishing == false)
    {
        cout << "\n" << i;
        string f = boost::to_string(Data);
        int sz = f.size();
        if (sz > 12)
        {
            vector<int> a;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
                a.push_back(i);
            a.clear();
        }
    }
}

void Run_io()
{
    while (process_all_finishing == false)
    {
        io_service_.run_one();
    }
    cout << "\nRun_io finished";
}

void receive()
{
    while (process_all_finishing == false)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < vecSock.size(); ++i)
        {
            vecSock[i]->async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(Data, 8000), vecEndpoint[i], boost::bind(receive_h,_1,_2,i));
        }
    }   
    cout << "\nreceive finished";
}

int main()
{
    timeBeginPeriod(1);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    try
    {
        ports.push_back(29005);
        ports.push_back(29007);
        ports.push_back(29009);
        ports.push_back(29001);

        vecSock.resize(3);
        vecEndpoint.resize(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            vecSock[i].reset(new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(io_service_, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), ports[i])));
        }
        boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread_re(new boost::thread(receive));
        boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread_io(new boost::thread(Run_io));

        receive_threads.push_back(thread_re);
        receive_threads.push_back(thread_io);
        cout << "\nvecSock=3 created, giving it to work for 1 second:";

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        process_all_finishing = true;
        cout << "\nSent flag to stop threads and wait for threads to finish for 1 second";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        for (int i = 0; i < vecSock.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << "\nSocket " << i << " opened =\t" << vecSock[i]->is_open();
            vecSock[i]->cancel();
            vecSock[i]->close();
            cout << "\nSocket " << i << " counter =\t" << vecSock[i].use_count();
            cout << "\nSocket " << i << " opened =\t" << vecSock[i]->is_open();
            vecSock[i].reset();
            cout << "\nSocket " << i << " counter =\t" << vecSock[i].use_count();
            cout << "\n";

        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        vecSock.clear();
        vecSock.resize(4);
        vecEndpoint.resize(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            vecSock[i].reset(new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(io_service_, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), ports[i])));
        }
        cout << "\nvecSock=4 created";
    }
    catch (boost::exception& e)
    {
        cerr <<"\n\a\a"<< boost::diagnostic_information(e);
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This causes an binding error (exeption) which i have redirected to console with `try-catch`.

> Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION) Dynamic
>   exception type: class boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > std::exception::what: bind: Usually are 
>   allowed only one usage of each socket address (Protocol/network
>   address/port)

Can ony one help? I have tried all, what I could find in references `c++` and `boost` and nothing helped this error.

Comment: Unrelated to your (current) problem, but having three asynchronous receives all use the same buffer is going to be prone to some confusion.

Comment: As for your problem, can you please elaborate on it? For example by showing the actual and expected outputs from the program?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it`s just an example which shows problem with sockets. In main project i have different buffers for each socket. Also they are presented as complex structure, which isn`t nessesary in this example. But good to notice it)

Comment: You may need to call `set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true))` on the socket to enable reuse. However, the `udp::socket` constructor that you're using opens and binds the socket as well. If you use the constructor that just takes an `io_service` you can `open` and `bind` the socket explicitly and then call `reuse_address` between `open` and `bind`.

Comment: @kenba i will add to question next update: if change `async_receive_from` to `receive_from` everything will be alright, no exeptions, no problems. Also i will have to use `reuse_address(true)` even if i`m binding to this socket for the first time, is it okey?

Comment: If it works with `receive_from` then you don't need `reuse_address(true)` although it's wise to use it anyway.  It may be that your issue with `async_receive_from` is because the code does't call `run`, `poll` or `poll_one` on the `io_service`, see this example [async_udp_echo_server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp)

Comment: @kenba as i know, without io_service.run() or io_service_.run_one() (run_one() in cycle) handlers wont work. But they work and io_service works too. In first place i thought that i must stop or reset it to finish handlers proceed and this caused problem, but not.

Comment: What is vecEndpoint[i]? You're just creating default constructed endpoints. Also, you should really be using a `work` object with your `io_service`, this forces the `io_service::run()` method to never exit unless you explicitly do so. Also, are you calling `::run()` before posting any work to the `io_service`? If not, the call will exit because there is no work, you'll try to run code that requires the service to be running and boom, you're chasing wild nonsensical errors around in the desert with no water.